# Campaign Member Validation rule limit user creation

Tags: validation-rule, campaign-member

I want to create a validation rule that basically limits the creation of a campaign member to the Api User for a specific campaign.
At this point I have:
AND(
CreatedBy.Id <> "005F0000004B4s0",Campaign.Id = "701F0000000fQbD")

For some reason even the API User is getting the error message when attempting to create a campaign member.

To me it makes sense, if the created by id is not "X" when the campaign ID is "Y" then don't allow it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use $User.Id instead of CreatedBy.ID. $User.Id is a session variable that stores the ID of the current user. Since the campaign member was not yet created, it did not have a CreatedBy.ID.

Comment: @Tyler - $User.alias, $User.firstname, $User.lastname, $userRole.name, or $Profile.name might be better choices than hard-coded userIds which provide no visual doc to the sysad